# PDF data into XML format using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, neural-network

Extracting text from PDF files  in python can be done using python different packages , but i am looking deep learning solution? How deep learning can be used to extract the text in format xml ?  Heard a lot of times deep learning can be used ? Can any one have any used case and explain the process?

Comment: Can you put here which steps or approach you are doing?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Answer (score 1):

The problem on PDF parsing is not the output but the process of page analysis. So if you analyze the page right you can output the results in any format you want (that should be the easy part). I would suggest to read the source code of pdfminer which I think is the most sophisticated so you can get started on how to start so you can parse a PDF. As for deep learning I think it will be complicated to do, but yes, it has application as the hardest issue with PDF files is to manage text orientation, line spaces, vertical or lateral, word margins etc. Good luck if you start a project and always remember that PDF is Evil.